# Issues with AWS Lambda Docker Container (permission denied)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am deploying a Docker container with AWS Lambda which executes a machine learning model. But whenever I attempt to load the saved checkpoints, I am getting a permission denied message when attempting to read the local filesystem or a no directory found based on where I am storing the model...?

Here is the relevant Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# copy requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt ./

# upgrade pip and install the python requirements from requirements.txt
RUN python3.8 -m pip install \
        --upgrade pip
RUN python3.8 -m pip install \
        -r requirements.txt

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ./

# Install the runtime interface client
RUN python3.8 -m pip install \
        awslambdaric

# clean up image for small container
RUN find . -type d -name "tests" -exec rm -rf {} +
RUN find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -rf {} +
RUN find . -type d -name "include" -exec rm -rf {} +
RUN rm -rf ./{caffe2,wheel,wheel-*,pkg_resources,boto*,aws*,pip,pip-*,pipenv,setuptools}
RUN rm -rf ./{*.egg-info,*.dist-info}
RUN find . -name \*.pyc -delete
RUN find . -type d -name "test" -exec rm -rf {} +
RUN ls -R -al

# update linux libraries
RUN yum update -y

# install python3 and unzip
RUN yum install -y python3 unzip

# pull model files
RUN mkdir ./model
RUN curl https://somewhere.com/model.zip -o ./model/model.zip
RUN unzip ./model/model.zip -d ./model
RUN chmod 644 ./model
RUN chmod -R 644 ./model/*
RUN rm ./model/model.zip

WORKDIR ./
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

And the app.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json, time
import urllib.request
from jose import jwk, jwt
from jose.utils import base64url_decode
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

model = ModelFunction('/model')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    body = json.loads(event['body'])

    token = body['jwttoken']
    utterance = body['utterance']
    comparestring = body['comparestring']

    # generate embeddings for each phrase
    embeddings1 = model.encode(utterance, convert_to_tensor=True)
    embeddings2 = model.encode(comparestring, convert_to_tensor=True)

    # compute score
    score = util.embeddings(embeddings1, embeddings2)

    # output score
    print("Score:")
    print(score.item())

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "score": json.dums(score.item())
    }

    # the following is useful to make this script executable in both
    # AWS Lambda and any other local environments
if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = {
        'token': '',
        'email': 'somewhere@somewhere.com'}
    lambda_handler(event, None)
```

A couple of the relevant error messages:

```
[ERROR] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './model/modules.json'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 8, in <module>
    model = model('./model')
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/model/model.py", line 115, in __init__
    with open(os.path.join(model_path, 'modules.json')) as fIn:
```

and

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sbx_user1051/.cache/model'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 8, in <module>
    model = model('/model')
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/model/model.py", line 101, in __init__
    shutil.rmtree(model_path)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 709, in rmtree
    onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 707, in rmtree
    orig_st = os.lstat(path)
```

Any ideas? I think I am not storing the model checkpoints in the correct directory? The above logs have been somewhat scrubbed due to NDA etc.

Comment: Hello, did @zarnoevic solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
chmod 644 $(find . -type f)
chmod 755 $(find . -type d)
```

on the files you're trying to deploy.

As the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-deployment.html) say, there may be a permissions issue if the files aren't set to be executable by any user.